# Can't print loop index as string : Python

Tags: python, string, loops

```
for r in range(31):
         if r>15:
             print(str(r))
```

> I am tring to use loop index as str but getting below error:

```
print(str(r))                                                      
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

Comment: Sounds as if you have overriden the built-in ``str`` (e.g. by assigning str = ... somewhere). Please provide the **complete** code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to convert integers to `str` to print them.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler realizes the `str` as a variable instead of a built-in function. Use another name to the variable you named `str` and it must be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it

```
for r in range(31):
     if r>15:
         print(r)
```

Now, this will work.
There is no need to convert it into string while printing.

Hope it will help :)